# Parse hive array<string> output into either json format or something like following

Tags: hive

I have a HIVE table with 3 columns, col3 is array the output from the table is like this

```
select col1, col2, col3 from testing;
col1     col2   col3
xyx      123    ["xyz","Good investing","123","abc","Bad investing","006","port123","future investing","008","flaf4","good research investing","01"]
xyx      789    ["xyz","Good investing","789","flag1","Bad investing","006","port123","future investing","008"]
```

I want to parse the col3 so that the output like as following

```
xyx      123    "xyz","Good investing","123"
xyx      123    "abc","Bad investing","006","port123"
xyx      123    "future investing","008","flaf4"
xyx      123    "good research investing","01"
xyx      789    "xyz","Good investing","789",
xyx      789    "flag1","Bad investing","006",
xyx      789    "port123","future investing","008"
```

any help will be highly appreciated
-kb

Comment: how do you want to break array result. question is not clear

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I would like to break array result in set of three element. for eg. [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,................] should be breaken into set of 3 element each like [0,1,2] of each in each row. hope this expain

Comment: Any Help will apprecaited